# How do I work with a connection in $TM$ when the inputs are vector fields defined ONLY on an open subset of $M$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let me introduce a definition first. If $M$ is a smooth $n$-manifold, then a connection in the tangent bundle $TM$ is a map $\nabla:\mathfrak{X}(M)\times\mathfrak{X}(M)\to\mathfrak{X}(M)$ that takes in smooth vector fields on $M$ and satisfies:

1. $\nabla_{f_1 X_1+f_2 X_2}\ Y=f_1 \nabla_{X_1}\ Y+f_2 \nabla_{X_2}\ Y$
2. $\nabla_X\ (a_1 Y_1+a_2 Y_2)=a_1\nabla_X Y_1+a_2\nabla_X Y_2$
3. $\nabla_X\ (fY)=f\nabla_X\ Y+(Xf)Y$

with obvious meaning of each symbol. For your information, this definition of a connection in $TM$ can be found in Lee's RM. After ushering in the definition, Lee defines the connection coefficients $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ of $\nabla$ w.r.t. a smooth local frame $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^n$ for $TM$ over an open subset $U$ of $M$ by setting
$$\nabla_{E_i}\ E_j=\Gamma_{ij}^k E_k.$$
Now that's where my question comes in. What is meant by $\nabla_{E_i}\ E_j$? After all, these $E_i$'s are ONLY defined locally on $M$ (they may not live in $\mathfrak{X}(M)$). I'm stuck in this question for a long time and try to make it out. Please help me out if you know something about it. Thank you.

Comment: To me, the best hope is to extend local fields $E_i$ to global ones $\tilde{E}_i$ and show that the choice of extension is irrelevant. That is, if $E_i$ can be extended to $\tilde{E}_i$ and $\bar{E}_i$, can we assure that $\nabla_{\tilde{E}_i}\ \tilde{E}_j=\nabla_{\bar{E}_i}\ \bar{E}_j$?

Comment: doesn't Lee have some propositions immediately after defining connections that $(\nabla_XY)(p)$ depends only on $X(p)$ and the values of $Y$ along a curve $\gamma$ whose tangent at $p$ is $X(p)$. Even if he doesn't prove the fully strengthened version of this dependence immediately, I surely recall him proving that $\nabla_XY$ is local wrt $X$ and $Y$ (i.e depends only on values of $X$ and $Y$ in an open neighborhood of $p$)

Comment: Yeah, he did. Lee has stated in a proposition that $(\nabla_X\ Y)_p$ depends only on the values of $Y$ in a nbd of $p$ and the value of $X$ at $p$. The thing is, can we extend each $E_i$ to a global vector field? There is indeed a lemma in Lee's ISM that helps me extend a vector field along a **closed** set $A\subseteq M$. But these $E_i$'s are all defined on an **open** set.

Comment: In doing $(\nabla_E\ F)_p$ with $E,F$ defined on an open set $U$, we can take care of $E$ by considering the closed set $\{p\}$ and using the extension lemma. How about the disturbing field $F$?

Comment: We can certainly find vector fields $X_i$ defined on $M$, such that there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $X_i|_U=E_i|_U$.

Comment: Can we build $X_i$ by employing a bump function or something? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the second paragraph on page 91 of *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds* (2nd edition). It says

> Thanks to Propositions 4.3 and 4.5, we can make sense of the
> expression $\nabla_v Y$ when $v$ is some element of $T_p M$ and $Y$ is a smooth local
> section of $E$ defined only on some neighborhood of $p$. To evaluate it,
> let $X$ be a vector field on a neighborhood of $p$ whose value at $p$ is $v$,
> and set $\nabla_v Y = \nabla_X Y|_p$. Proposition 4.5 shows that the result does not
> depend on the extension chosen. Henceforth, we will interpret
> covariant derivatives of local sections of bundles in this way without
> further comment.

Proposition 4.3 shows that a connection on a vector bundle $E\to M$ automatically determines a unique connection on the restriction of $E$ to any open subset of $M$; this is what justifies applying the connection to a vector field defined only on an open subset. Proposition 4.5 then says that the value of $\nabla_X Y$ at a point $p$ depends only on the value of $X$ at $p$; this is what justifies the notation $\nabla_v Y$ for a vector $v\in T_p M$.

To actually compute the value of $\nabla_v Y$ at a point $p\in M$, just choose a local frame defined on a neighborhood of $p$, compute the connection coefficients in that local frame, and use the formula you displayed in your post. There's no need to extend anything to a global vector field.

Comment: Hi professor, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243335/could-someone-explain-how-john-m-lee-defines-the-integration-over-the-boundary), please? Unfortunately I did not completely understand integration over the boundary of a manifolds with corners and so I have thought you can help me. Excuse me for the bother.