# Could someone explain how John M. Lee defines the integration over the boundary of a manifold with corners?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, proof-explanation, differential-forms, manifolds-with-boundary

In the $10$-th chapter of the text *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* written by John M. Lee it is written what put to follow.

> *The boundary of a smooth manifold with corners, however, is in general not a smooth manifold with corners (think of the boundary of a cube, for example). In fact, even the boundary of $\overline{\Bbb R^n_+}$ itself is not a smooth manifold with corners. It is, however, a union of finitely many such: $\partial\overline{\Bbb R^n_+}=H_1\cup\dots\cup H_n$, where
> $$
> H_i:=\{(x^1,\dots,x^n)\in\overline{\Bbb R^n_+}:x^i=0\}
> $$
> is an $(n-1)$-dimensional smooth manifold with corners contained in the subsapce defined by $x^i=0$.*
>
> *The usual flora and fauna of smooth manifolds -smooth maps, partitions of unity, tangent vectors, covectors, tensors, differential forms, orientations and integrals of differential forms- can be defined on smooth manifolds with corners in exactly the same way as we have done for smooth manifolds and smooth manifolds with boundary, using smooth charts with corners in place of smooth charts or generalized charts. The details are left to the reader.*
>
> *In addition, for Stokes's thorem we will need to integrate a differential form over the boundary of a smooth manifold with corners. Since the boundary is not itself a smooth manifold with corners, this requires a special definition. Let $M$ be an oriented smooth $n$-manifold with corners, and suppose $\omega$ is an $(n-1)$-form on $\partial M$ that is compactly supported in the domain of a single oriented smooth chart with corners $(U,\varphi)$. We define the integral of $\omega$ over $\partial M$ by
> $$
> \int_{\partial M}\omega:=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{H_i}(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega
> $$
> where each $H_i$ is given the induced orientation as part of the boundary of the set where $x^i\ge 0$. [...] Finally, if $\omega$ is an arbitrary compactly supported $(n-1)$-form on $M$, we define the integral of $\omega$ over $\partial M$ by piecing together with a partition of unity just as in the case of a manifold with boundary.*

So unfortunately I did not completely understand the definition of the integral of $\omega$ on $\partial M$: in particular if the coordinate patch $\varphi^{-1}$ is defined in an open set $U$ of $\overline{\Bbb R^n_+}$ then why the integral
$$
\int_{H_i}(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega
$$
is well defined if generally $U$ is not contained in $H_i$? Anyway it seems to me that Lee is implicitly claiming that the boundary of a $n$-manifold with corners is equal to union of $n$ $(n-1)$-manifolds with corners so that he integrates $\omega$ over each such manifolds but I am not sure about. After all $H_i$ is a $(n-1)$-manifolds with corners contained in $\overline{\Bbb R^n_+}$ and $U$ is there open so that $U\cap H_i$ is an open set of $H_i$ and thus in particular it is a $(n-1)$-manifold with corners so that the integral
$$
\int_{U\cap H_i}(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega
$$
is well defined but I am not sure that it is equal to the first. Anyway $(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega$ is compactly supported and its support is contained in $U$ that is open in $\Bbb R^n$ or in $[0,+\infty)^n$ so that it can be exteded to a smooth function defined in $\Bbb R^n$ and so in $H_i$ and thus effectively the integral
$$
\int_{H_i}(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega
$$
is well defined. So is the last a good explanation? Moreover I am not sure that $(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega$ can be extended to a smooth $(n-1)$-form defined in $\Bbb R^n$. So could someone help me, please?

**I point out I did not really study Lee's book but I only consulted it for pratical reasons -i.e. I am studying Continuum Mechanics and so I am ran into integration on manifolds with corners. However I studied the integration on manifolds (with boundary) on the text *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres but it seems that Lee formalism can be easily adapted to that of Munkres and vice versa. So I put [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xomc.png) some reference about Munkres formalism for an easily comunication.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, on an $n$-manifold with corners there may be more or less than $n$ boundary hypersurfaces. Consider e.g. $M=[0,1]^2$. It is true however, that $M=\mathbb{R}_+^n$ has exactly $n$ boundary hypersurfaces.

What is going on in the integration is just that first, $\omega$ is pulled back via the chart to yield an $n-1$-form $\alpha = (\varphi^{-1})^*\omega $ on some open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}_+^n$. You are right in saying that $U$ is not contained in any hypersurface $H_i$. But that is no problem, you can just restrict $\alpha$ to $U\cap H_i$ (aka: pull back via the inclusion map $U\cap H_i\rightarrow U$) to get an $n-1$-form on $U\cap H_i$, for which integration is well defined.

Comment: Oh yeah, perhaps I understood: the set $H_i$ is closed and the support of $\alpha$ is compact so that the support of its restriction to $U\cap H_i$ is surely compact (is this right?) so that the identity $$\int_{H_i}\alpha=\int_{U\cap H_i}\alpha$$ holds but I have some trouble about again: so is the last claim flase? could you explain it better, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: Anyway it seems your counterexample does not work: in fact the union of two opposite side of $[0,1]^2$ is a $1$-manifolds with corners (exactly the disjoint union of compact manifolds with corners is again a compact manifold with corners) so that the boundary of $[0,1]^2$ is obviously union of two 1-manifolds with corners.

Comment: Try to show that the inclusion $\iota \colon H_i\cap U \rightarrow U$ is a *proper map*. This will imply that $\iota^*\alpha$ is compactly supported in $U\cap H_i$, such that $\int_{U\cap H_i}\iota^*\alpha$ is well defined as the integral of a smooth, compactly supported volume form on an $n-1$ manifold.

Regarding the square: Fair enough, if you want to consider disconnected manifolds. But this is just a coincidence, look a triangle instead.

Comment: Okay, but why $$\int_{U\cap H_i} \iota^* \alpha=\int_{H_i}\iota^* \alpha$$ if $\iota^* \alpha$ is only defined in $U\cap H_i$?

Comment: Well this question doesn't have anything to with differential forms anymore. If $V\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is open and $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function wit compact support, then can you make sense of the equality $\int_V f dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f dx$?

Comment: Okay, pheraps I understood. So $(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega$ is a $k$-form defined in an open set of $\Bbb R^k$ or in an open set of $[0,+\infty)^k$ so that $$(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega=f\cdot dx^1\curlywedge\dots\curlywedge dx^k$$ where $f$ is a scalar function defined in the domain $U$ of $\varphi^{-1}$. So observing that the support of $f|_{U\cap H_i}$ is compact then Lee puts $$\int_{\partial M}\omega:=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{U\cap H_i} f=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{H_i} f$$ because $f$ vanishes in $H_i\setminus U$, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok, answer upvoted; just give me some time to approve it: I'd like to reflect about it just a little time, that's all. Anyway thanks very much for your assistance: you helped a lot, thanks yet.

Comment: Sorry but my claim is false: indeed $\omega$ is an $(k-1)$ form so that even $(\varphi^{-1})^*$ is a $(k-1)$-form and thus the identity $$(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega=f\cdot dx^1\curlywedge\dots\curlywedge dx^k$$ has not make sense.

Comment: So for now I can not accept your answer, sorry again.

Comment: Well, you didn't say what $k$ is -- I assume now $k=n$ equals the dimension of the manifold $M$. Then yes, $\alpha$ is an $n-1$-form and thus can be written as $f_1 dx^2\wedge \dots dx^n + f_2 dx^1 \wedge dx^3 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^n + \dots $ (so after $f_i$ the $1$-form $dx^i$ is left out).  Pull this back by $\iota$ to $H_i=\{x_i=0\}$ and see what happens ...

Comment: Yes, you said well: k=n. So if I well understood you say that since the restriction of $\alpha:=(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega$ to $U\cap H_i$ (i.e. $\iota^*\alpha$) is compactly supported so that it can be exteded to a smooth $(n-1)$-form defined in $H_i$ so that the integral $$\int_{H_i}\iota^*\alpha$$ is well defined **as integral of a $(n-1)$-form over a $(n-1)$ manifolds with corners**, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. However $H_i$ neither has corners nor a boundary.

Comment: Why $H_i$ has no corner points? Indeed Lee defines it taking the intersection of the hyperplane $x_i=0$ with $\overline{\Bbb R^n_+}$ and so it seems to me that it has corner points and precisely every points of $\overline{\Bbb R^n_+}$ with $x_i,x_j=0$ for $i\neq j$ is a corner or boundary points for $H_i$: so is this incorrect?

Comment: Moreover Lee says this explicitely: read the reference I reported above.

Comment: You are right, I thought of $H_i$ as hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but you indeed take the intersection with a quadrant which does create corners,

Comment: Okay, so now it seems all clear but just give me some time to approve your anser: I'd like to reflect about it just a little time -only any hours, that's all.

Comment: Question approved, thanks very much for your support!!!